# Apache Storm 2: Could not find leader nimbus from seed hosts

Tags: apache-storm

I could not able to launch apache storm, getting error like as shown in below

storm.yaml as

```
    ########### These MUST be filled in for a storm configuration
     storm.zookeeper.servers:- "localhost"
     nimbus.seeds: ["localhost"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

how are you running your components? (Zookeeper, Nimbus, etc.)

- Are you sure they are accessible under localhost?
  e.g. using Docker-compose services called zookeeper and nimbus:
  -> in storm.yaml:

  *storm.zookeeper.servers: [zookeeper]
  nimbus.seeds: [nimbus]*
- Other idea: for me this error occured frequently when my Zookeeper instance was corrupted, (e.g. because I did not recreate Zookeper container after rebuilding the rest of the Cluster).

Answer (score 0):

Is it just a typo? You wrote:  `storm.zookeeper.servers:- "localhost"`
So perhaps try to delete the `-`. And check your `nimbus.log`, it that error still occurs.